# Mac get selected text from foremost window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-elcapitan

I am building a menu app that needs to be able to capture selected text and then act on it. This will of course be a sandboxed app. Is there a standard way of capturing selected text from any window in the foreground? This could be any app, a browser and so on.

Comment: Have you considered writing a [Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html) instead? The interaction model is different: the user is working in the third-party app, has some text selected, and chooses a Service to operate on that text. The text is **given** to your Service implementation and you can give back some text to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want to do.  As far as I know, the only way to look at text in another app is by using the "assistive" APIs.  But according to the [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html),

> you cannot sandbox an assistive app such as a screen reader, and you cannot sandbox an app that controls another app

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy using the Assistive API as well. So far I'm having trouble trying to make my app show up in the Security & Privacy pane for Accessibility, even though I'm trying to check if my app is trusted like so: `  NSDictionary *options = @{(__bridge id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @YES};
  BOOL accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);`